# Extracting String from XML files with loop in Python

Tags: python, xml, loops, extract

[image]

I have 14 different XML files like this and I'm trying to get ActionUnit Number values (ex. 45 and 5). I need to do it for the other 13 XML files too with a loop. After that, I need to create subfolders for each value that I extracted. I tried a code for value extraction but I get none as a result;

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree= ET.ElementTree(file=r'C:\Users\LME_s\Desktop\python quiz\Sessions\1\S001-001-oao_aucs.xml')
root= tree.getroot()
for chld in root:
   print (chld.get('ActionUnit Number'))
```

Comment: Please upload the xml as text and not as image

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually few questions...
Here is how to extract the data you need from the xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML = '''<ActionUnitCoding>
            <ActionUnit Number="45"></ActionUnit>
            <ActionUnit Number="5"></ActionUnit>
        </ActionUnitCoding>'''
root = ET.fromstring(XML)
numbers = [e.attrib['Number'] for e in root.findall('.//ActionUnit')]
print(numbers)
```

output

```
['45', '5']
```

Comment: I get this error when i try to use location Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LME_s\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(tree)
  File "C:\Users\LME_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1347, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'

Comment: 1) did you try my code as is? Did it work? 2) what is the code that raise the he exception?

Comment: Your code is working but I need to access XML file with infernal path. So this block"root = ET.fromstring(XML)" is not working for me. I tried to use root= tree.getroot() function but it will not take 2 different value.

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file_name.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

Comment: TypeError: getroot() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given