# Creating folders using loop

Tags: python, xml, directory, operating-system, mkdir

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import os
path = r'C:\Users\LME_s\Desktop\python quiz\Sessions'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    root=tree.getroot()
    numbers = [e.attrib['Number'] for e in root.findall('.//ActionUnit')]
    base_path = r'C:\Users\LME_s\Desktop\python quiz\Sessions/new'
    for folder in numbers:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(base_path, folder))
        
    #print(numbers)
```

I created a loop that reads XML data and put this data on the array dynamically. This is the output, So here is my question. In each iteration, I need to create folders named "AU45" and  "not AU45" for each array element. Here is a problem, in the first iteration I created a folder which is named "10" but in the next iteration I also have another 10 value and I get an exception because a folder named "10" also exists. How can I avoid this?

[image: outrpu]

Comment: Could you expand a little more on the structure of how the folders are named? typically it's a two line solution first check if path to folder exists then if the folder does not exist create it.  os.makedirs(path/to/folder)

Comment: Ok, I created a new code block that creates a folder name for each array element but I have another problem. Can you check the code line; I get an error because in the loop I created a folder which is named "10" before and it gives an error because I have another "10" in another array.

Comment: So I'm not sure of what you're trying to accomplish.  Why is it an issue if the folder 10 already exists? Do you want to write the new file in the same folder? Is it an error when creating the folder?  Without you being specific it really is almost impossible to help.

Comment: Did you see my array outputs in each iteration? I'm reading a value from each XML file and pushing it into an array. So in each iteration, I'm creating a folder, and the folder's names are equal to the array values. In the first iteration, I create folders named 45 and 5, in the second 10 and 25, and in the third iteration, I get an exception because a folder named 10 already exists and I get an exception that this folder already exists you can not create another folder. I need to avoid this. So basically I need a function that skips array values that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the created folders in a set.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import os
path = r'C:\Users\LME_s\Desktop\python quiz\Sessions'
created_folders = set()
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    root=tree.getroot()
    numbers = [e.attrib['Number'] for e in root.findall('.//ActionUnit')]
    base_path = r'C:\Users\LME_s\Desktop\python quiz\Sessions/new'
    for folder in numbers:
        if folder not in created_folders:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(base_path, folder))
            created_folders.add(folder)
```

Comment: @EmreSarı See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276888/extracting-string-from-xml-files-with-loop-in-python/65277024#65277024 - it is my previous answer for the same task you are facing. Feel free to vote up :-)

Comment: I can't because I'm on 11 reputations, but I will :D

Comment: Can I ask one more question, now I'm trying to copy .avi files to related folders but I get NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] : 'C:\\Users\\LME_s\\Desktop\\python quiz\\Sessions\\S001-001.avi' I'm using same path as XML's path. But i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: the avi is a  file - not a directory.

Comment: For shutil.copy function did not I need exact location? I'm using the .avi file's location and new location; shutil.copytree(avilocation,new location) am i doing it wrong?

Comment: I think you better create a new question, share the code that does the copy and explain what is the issue.

Comment: I created a new question btw.